# pexpect not found

Tags: restore, duplicity

How can I get pexpect for duplicity? I was trying to my backup files with the following cmd

```
duplicity restore -v8 --no-encryption "par2+file:/home/ken/backup" "home/ken/documents"
```

it errors out with

> "Giving up after 5 attempts. ImportError: No module named pexpect"

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you installed duplicity?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Ubuntu version you have to install one of the following Python Expect packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pexpect
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pexpect
```

and then run Duplicity again.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the                                                    sudo apt-get install python3-pexpect                                    python3-pexpect is already the newest version (4.0.1-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  snapd-login-service
U

Comment: On a similar issue `python-pexpect` was the missing package on debian stretch for me.